# schedule report with a parameter

Tags: powerbi

I currently use IBM Cognos Analytics.  I have the ability to create a prompt page that asks the user for input.  With this prompt page available, I can then schedule the report to run and send to one or more recipients.  I can even choose which parameter values to use for each set of users.  The parameter values can be text, date, or numeric.

Imagine I have two managers who want output from the same report every day, but one wants to see bicycle sales and one wants to see clothing sales.  I would use the same report for both managers.  One can receive the results filtered to bicycles and the other gets results filtered to clothing.

How would I do this in Power BI?

Looking at the "New parameter" tool, I see I can create a parameter for Whole number, Decimal number, or Fixed decimal number.  It doesn't appear to allow other data types.  (But maybe "parameter" is not what I should be looking for.  Microsoft seems to have its own vocabulary.)

How can a Power BI user subscribe to a report and specify the parameters values to give them only the data they care about?

Update:

I want to know how to do this using both Import and using Direct Query.    I imagine some of the reports users may want to schedule will be "published to web" which requires the data to be imported into the report.

Update 2:

This question is about Power BI reports, not paginated reports.

Comment: This can be done for subscriptions sent to other people on Paginated Reports: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/consumer/end-user-subscribe#paginated-reports-parameters  For subscriptions for yourself, when you navigate back to the report it remembers your last set of filters.

Comment: Just to clarify - do you want to do this with Cognos?

Comment: Nope.  I've been using Cognos (report view, schedules, event studio agents, event triggers, etc.) for 7 years.  No problems there.  Just trying to figure out how to do the same things in Power BI.